# Git: Get the size of a uncommitted changes

Tags: git

Is there a way to see the size of my uncommitted changes in git?  I guess if there's a way to see the size of committed changes, I could temporarily commit my stuff and look at that commit.  Is there a way to do this?

The reason is that I'm worried that my uncommitted changes that include a bunch of binary file changes might be unnecessarily large, which would then increase the size of the git repo forever.  So I want to look for another solution if it is.

Comment: I think the trick is to commit the changes and then somehow use `git bundle`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `git diff --binary`, though that's formatting the binary patch in text form, thus making it larger than it actually is.

But it should be sufficient to get a quick grasph on whether we're talking kilobytes, megabytes or even more ;-)

For instance, you could do `git diff --cached --binary | wc -c` prior to committing.

Comment: Except without the `--cached`, because I don't use the staging area.